# SVG line stroke-dasharray not print properly to PDF

Tags: pdf, svg, webkit, stroke-dasharray

Print line with `stroke-dasharray` to PDF create different behavior, please
look at the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doOku.png) here.

**Picture A**, a screenshot I took directly from the browser (Chrome). **Picture B** is the printed PDF from the same page.

Notice the difference in Picture B, there's a thin line between the dash, this happens in Chrome or PhantomJS (probably WebKit related?) and not happen in Firefox.

What I trying to do is export this kind of [chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065609/draw-gridline-tickline-at-a-specific-tick-in-d3-js) to PDF, but as you can see `strokoe-dasharray` not printed properly.

That picture above I took from this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) page, Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: On my system (OS X/Chrome), I'm seeing the extra strokes in the print preview, but not in the exported PDF. What workarounds have you tried so far? [The SVG sample you're working with](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray$samples/Example?revision=648037) contains [invalid markup](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmdn.mozillademos.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FSVG%2FAttribute%2Fstroke-dasharray%24samples%2FExample%3Frevision%3D648037&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), so fixing that might help. Try using Inkscape instead?

Comment: Ah, stupid me. I forgot to add attribute `fill="none"`, thanks for point it out. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 20):

It seems that this is caused by some default value for the `fill` attribute. You can fix it by setting `fill="none"`, like this:

```
<line x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0"
  stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1, 2"
  fill="none"
/>
```

Comment: This looks like [Chrome bug #123072](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123072), but that was  closed in 2012 so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this problem now.

Comment: This still exists in chrome v65. `fill='none'` fixed the issue.

Comment: Bug still exists in chrome v71. `fill='none'` fixed it

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this, adding `fill='none'` did the trick for me as well.

Comment: what would be the fix here if you need both stroke and fill ?