# PDF created by inkscape contains thin gray line through dashed line

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I have the following svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 0.5 0.5" version="1.1" height="300">
    <g transform="translate(-0.25,-0.2)" stroke-width="0.001" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="0.0065">
        <line y2="-0.05" y1="0.05" x2="-0.02" x1="0.08"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

which renders as

[image]

on Edge and Firefox. I want to convert this svg to a pdf with LaTeX support, which is why I use inkscape on the WSL:

```
_INKSCAPE_GC=disable inkscape -D img.svg --export-type="pdf" --export-filename=test.pdf --export-latex
```

The fist part of the command is due to [this bug](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1420).

Adobe Acrobat (and the TeXstudio integrated renderer) render the created pdf as

[image]

If you look closely, you can see a very thin gray line connecting the dashes. Why is that? How do I remove that?

Comment: tested with inkscape 0.92 and 1.0 ([Appimage](https://inkscape.org/de/release/inkscape-master/gnulinux/appimage/)) on Linux Mint Debian Edition 4 does not show the error when rendered with libpoppler-glib8 (evince and others). The same file rendered with Acrobat Reader DS or libpoppler-qt5 (Okular) does show the line. TeXstudio as a qt application unfortunately also uses libpoppler-qt5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450905). The problem seemed to be similiar. Indeed, setting `fill="none"` on the `line` or the enclosing `g` solves the problem. That does of course not fully explain the problem, which is why I leave the question open for now. This does however provide a workround if someone encounters the same problem.